# Calculating matrix points from input Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix of co-ordinates, like `[x1 y1 z1; x2 y2 z2; ... xn yn zn]`.
Currently, these co-ordinates are input manually, however, I want to just enter `x1`,`y1`,`z1` and by a for-loop, calculate other points well:
`x1=7`, `y1=-x^2`, `z1=tanx` and it calculates the other points by decreasing `x1` by 1 (e.g. 6, 5, 4 and so on) and by this calculating the other `x2`, `y2`, `z2` and so on, finally resulting in the array `[x1 y1 z1; x2 y2 z2; ... xn yn zn]`.

**Edit 1:**
How if I want the `x,y,z` equations in argument as `x1=7`, `y1=-x^2`, `z1=tanx` ?

My Code:

```
function funC(x1,y1,z1)
x=7;
y=-x^2;
z=tanx;
for ii=1:7
    array = [x-1 y z];
    %not showing correct result
end
```

Comment: `x = 7:-1:1; array = [x.' (-x.^2).' tan(x).']`

Comment: @Divakar plz see edit 1 of current question.

Comment: How does your edit change the validity of @Divakar 's suggestion? Please provide an example of your desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [anonymous functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html). First, create your function, like this:

```
function array = funC(x1, y1, z1)
    x = (x1:-1:1).';
    array = [x y1(x) z1(x)];
end
```

Then, call it like this:

```
% Define x1
>> x1 = 7

% Define y1 and z1 as anonymous functions
>> y1 = @(x) -x.^2;
>> z1 = @(x) tan(x);

% Call your function
>> funC(x1,y1,z1)

ans =

    7.0000  -49.0000    0.8714
    6.0000  -36.0000   -0.2910
    5.0000  -25.0000   -3.3805
    4.0000  -16.0000    1.1578
    3.0000   -9.0000   -0.1425
    2.0000   -4.0000   -2.1850
    1.0000   -1.0000    1.5574
```